# Why is it dangerous to cast List<out X> to List<X>

Tags: kotlin

Let say we have a list of:

```
val list: MutableList<out X> = mutableListOf(...)
val list2 = list as MutableList<X>
```

As the result we have a warning `Unchecked cast: MutableList<out X> to MutableList<X>`

Why this cast is dangerous in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MutableList<out X>` is a list which contains elements of a specific type which is a subclass of X. By casting it to `MutableList<X>`, you're also allowing to add other elements to this list, which are also of type X but not of the same subclass. For example:

```
class StringHolder {
    val strings = ArrayList<String>()
    val list: MutableList<out Any> = strings
    fun process() {
        for (s in strings) {
            s.length
        }
    }
}

fun hack(holder: StringHolder) {
    val list = holder.list as MutableList<Any>
    list.add(1)
    holder.process() // fails with ClassCastException casting Int to String
}
```